# How does the open() function converts a binary content received from requests to an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests

link = 'https://imageio.forbes.com/specials-images/imageserve/5d35eacaf1176b0008974b54/2020-Chevrolet-Corvette-Stingray/0x0.jpg?format=jpg&crop=4560,2565,x790,y784,safe&width=960'

get_requests = requests.get(link)

image_content = get_requests.content


with open('testimage.jpg', 'wb') as image_convert:
    
    write_content = image_convert.write(image_content)
    
    print(write_content)
```

how is the binary content converted here by the `open()` function to an image ?

Comment: i wanna know how the open function was able to convert the binary content to and image

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a conversion happening. `open` returns a file object, then the `bytes` returned from the call to `request.get` are written to the disk using that file object. An image is just data; represented here as a Python `bytes` object.

Comment: but the confusing part is : when i try to copy the content i get from requests and put it in a jpg format on my computer the picture never appears when i convert the binary content i get to an image using python i get the right picture i know the picture is just numbers how are these numbers identified ???

Comment: @python If you're just opening a text editor and pasting the numbers in, that won't work. If you go into notepad, type the number `9`, then save the file, it's actually the number 57 written to the disk (the ASCII code associated with the number `9`). To do it manually, you would need to use a hex editor or some other editor that lets you set the actual byte values.

Comment: what do you mean by written to the disk which disk ???????

Comment: @python Your harddrive/SSD/whatever your computer is using for storage.

Comment: i have ssd but where is the these content numbers written in the disk which file ?

Comment: @python Whatever file you created.

Comment: so the write function writes to the disk but how is this done ? why i cannot see the binary content that's written to the disk ?? do you have any channel or article i can read to understand ?

Comment: so what i understood is  : write() function whenever i tell it to write something like : write('hello world') it is actually going to write the binarry content of 'hello world' to the disk an wherever that binary code is it is going to be represented in the file i mentioned in open() function am i right ?

Comment: @python I'm not sure what you mean by "wherever that binary code is", but yes, that otherwise sounds about right.

Comment: are the data written to the disk first or the file first ?

Comment: but how is it stored in the disk is there a location for this binary data i am really sorry i just don't understand